# installing jekyll-coffeescript on Fedora 19

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, coffeescript, fedora, octopress

I'm trying to use jekyll-coffeescript on Fedora 19 to get my octopress working. 'rake generate' keeps failing, I'm not sure why, I think all the dependencies are installed ok. I have tried installing loads of different modules but none of them solve the problem. I have nodejs installed and rubyracer.

If you need anymore info from me to help, let me know and I'll post it.

this is for an octopress install.

```
#( 09/04/14@ 9:07am )( tim@localhost ):~/Workspace/Development/octopress@source✔
   rake generate                  
## Generating Site with Jekyll
identical source/stylesheets/screen.css 
  Dependency Error:  Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-coffeescript or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- json' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at http://jekyllrb.com/help/! 
/home/tim/.gem/ruby/gems/jekyll-2.3.0/lib/jekyll/deprecator.rb:56:in `rescue in block in gracefully_require': jekyll-coffeescript (Jekyll::Errors::MissingDependencyException)
    from /home/tim/.gem/ruby/gems/jekyll-2.3.0/lib/jekyll/deprecator.rb:45:in `block in gracefully_require'
    from /home/tim/.gem/ruby/gems/jekyll-2.3.0/lib/jekyll/deprecator.rb:44:in `each'
    from /home/tim/.gem/ruby/gems/jekyll-2.3.0/lib/jekyll/deprecator.rb:44:in `gracefully_require'
    from /home/tim/.gem/ruby/gems/jekyll-2.3.0/lib/jekyll.rb:141:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/tim/.gem/ruby/gems/jekyll-2.3.0/bin/jekyll:6:in `require'
    from /home/tim/.gem/ruby/gems/jekyll-2.3.0/bin/jekyll:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/tim/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /home/tim/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
#( 09/04/14@ 9:09am )( tim@localhost ):~/Workspace/Development/octopress@source✔
   gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.0)
blankslate (2.1.2.4)
bundler (1.7.2)
celluloid (0.15.2)
chunky_png (1.3.1, 1.2.7)
classifier-reborn (2.0.1)
coffee-script (2.3.0, 2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.7.1, 1.6.1)
colorator (0.1)
commonjs (0.2.6)
compass (0.12.7, 0.12.6)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.2.1, 1.4.0)
fast-stemmer (1.0.2)
ffi (1.9.3)
fssm (0.2.10, 0.2.7)
haml (4.0.5)
hpricot (0.8.6)
io-console (0.4.2)
jekyll (2.3.0)
jekyll-coffeescript (1.0.1, 1.0.0)
jekyll-gist (1.1.0)
jekyll-paginate (1.0.0)
jekyll-sass-converter (1.2.0)
jekyll-sitemap (0.5.1)
jekyll-watch (1.1.0)
json (1.7.7)
kramdown (1.4.1)
libv8 (3.16.14.3 x86_64-linux, 3.11.8.13 x86_64-linux)
liquid (2.6.1)
listen (2.7.9, 0.4.7)
mercenary (0.3.4)
multi_json (1.7.1)
octopress-date-format (2.0.1)
octopress-hooks (2.2.1)
parslet (1.5.0)
posix-spawn (0.3.9)
psych (2.0.0)
pygments.rb (0.6.0)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-protection (1.5.3)
rake (10.3.2)
rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
rb-inotify (0.9.5)
rdiscount (2.1.7.1)
rdoc (4.0.1)
redcarpet (3.1.2)
RedCloth (4.2.9)
ref (1.0.2)
ruby_parser (3.1.1)
rubypants (0.2.0)
safe_yaml (1.0.3)
sass (3.3.8, 3.2.19)
sass-globbing (1.0.0)
sassy-maps (0.4.0)
sexp_processor (4.1.5)
sinatra (1.4.5)
stringex (1.4.0)
therubyracer (0.12.1, 0.11.3)
tilt (1.4.1)
timers (1.1.0)
toml (0.1.1)
yajl-ruby (1.1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this very helpful blogpost, basically you need to install RVM and setup ruby correctly, the steps are listed in the following post:

https://gist.github.com/lowstz/1739538